# Как удалять невидимые символы в CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Доброе время суток, форумчане!

Как можно  реализовать удаление  невидимых символов При вставке скопированного  текста с (word,pdf, b и т.д.) в  CKeditor?